# Why does curl_setopt_array break requests and curl_setopt doesn't?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, php-7.4

when i try to make a request implementing `curl_setopt_array` it doesn't work and sophos returns an error:

```php
<?php
try {
$url    = 'http://127.0.0.1/index.php';
$fields = array(
    'JsonData'=>json_encode(['test' => 'test'])
);
$postvars         = http_build_query($fields);
$options  = [
    CURLOPT_URL               => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST              => count($fields),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS        => $postvars,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 2,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => false,
    CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE      => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT    => 2,
    CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT     => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER        => array('Connection: close')
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo 'Finish!!!'
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

note: `curl_setopt_array` return `true` but, when perform the `curl_exec` my sophos firewall return error:

> Error: Content could not be delivered fue to the folloeing condition: Invalid argument

when i tried to make a request by implementing `curl_setopt` works correctly and not get a sophos interruption:

```php
<?php
try {
$url    = 'http://127.0.0.1/index.php';
$fields = array(
    'JsonData'=>json_encode(['test' => 'test'])
);
$postvars         = http_build_query($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo 'Finish!!!'
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Why the second works correctly and the first does not work? From my point of view I'm doing the same...**

Comment: Does the error message not give details of the line where the error occurred?

Comment: nope if i try the same with the other curl way ... work fine ... but the problem is around set the option with `curl_setopt_array`, I assume that something is happening internally that doesn't happen with `curl_setopt`

Comment: if it was an error in my php code; I'm sure it would pop with some error or exception... I've also placed an exception handler in my code that never fires...

Comment: There is a trailing comma within the options but doubt that is the cause

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I have removed the comma at the end and tried again and no change the error still occurs.

Comment: I've tested both ( with one other option added for SSL connections and a url pertinent to my dev server ) and both work 100% OK - I could detect no difference between both methods. You mention Sophos - disable it and try again?!

Comment: I've already done it; and it is sophos that tells me that there is something wrong in the request between one option and the other.

if both work correctly; I don't understand what differences sophos detects to say that the option implemented by curl_setopt_array is malicious or there are invalid arguments; sophos does not alter anything...